# Combination Of Sets Question

Tags: logic, combinations

I have a bit of an advanced combination problem that has left me stumped for a few days. Essentially my question is if you have n sets of items, and you can select a different number of items from each set, how do you compute the combinations without first creating new sets.

An example in pictures:
I have three sets:

Set A has elements: 
Dog
Cat
Rhino
Set B has elements:

Pig

Horse

Cow

Set C has elements:

Lizard

Snake

Crocodile

Alligator

And now I would like to compute all of the combinations with the criteria that 2 elements be selected from set a, 1 element is selected from set 
B, and 2 elements are selected from set C.

The end result would contain all the unique combinations with those specifications.
A current way I am using is to take Set A and turn Set A into all of the combinations of Set A that has 2 elements and storing it in a different set, Set D, then doing the same for Set C, storing in Set E, and then selecting one item from each Set B, Set D, and Set E to get all the unique combinations but I was wondering if there was a better solution.

EDIT: By compute I am referring to generating a list of all the possible sets, NOT figure out the count or number of items. That being said, this implies that each set must be unique (Dog, Cat, Pig, Lizard, Snake) is the same as (Cat, Dog, Pig, Snake, Lizard).

Comment: By "compute" do you mean "count", or are you looking for an algorithm to generate a list of sets?

Comment: I am trying to generate a list of the sets

Answer (score 1):

Assuming "compute" means "count".

> And now I would like to compute all of the combinations with the criteria that 2 elements be selected from set A (3 elements), 1 element is selected from set B (3 elements), and 2 elements are selected from set C (4 elements).

$${^{3}{\rm C}_{2}}{^{3}{\rm C}_{1}}{^{4}{\rm C}_{2}} = \frac{3!}{2!1!}\cdot\frac{3!}{1!2!}\cdot\frac{4!}{2!^2} = 3\cdot 3\cdot 6 = 54$$

Comment: When I say compute I need the actual  sets of data. This means I need those 54 sets stored. I do not really care too much about how many their are, I just need the actual sets.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a good approach.  Combinations from A are {Dog, Cat}, {Dog, Rhino}, and {Cat Rhino}. There are 3 combinations for set B, and 6 combinations for set C. Thus you  will have $3*3*6=54$ different sets that meet your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to visualize all the combinations is to use a tree diagram. It will, however, get rather unwieldy, since as the other answers showed you'll end up with 54 branches.

First, list the three combinations of 2 elements of $A$, say $(a_1,a_2),(a_1,a_3)$, and $(a_2,a_3)$. From each these spring out 3 branches, one for each element of $B$ (because you're only looking for 1 element of $B$). Then from each of the branches will spring out 6 branches, one for each of the combinations of 2 elements of $C$: $(c_1, c_2),(c_1,c_3),(c_1,c_4),(c_2,c_3),(c_2,c_4),$ and $(c_3,c_4)$.

To read a particular combination, you can trace your path back along each branch.